# Mario kart 8 gamepad menu

Tags: mario-kart-8

This is really bothering me. I clicked on the ingame menu so I could use my tv.  I just play on the gamepad. Now I can't figure out how to go back. I have no map just two duplicated screens. This is really driving me nuts. I want to go back and play on the tv but there is no prompt or button that shows how.

Comment: Have you tried touching anywhere on the gamepad's screen? Anywhere at all?

Answer (score 3):

Try touching the gamepad screen.  It goes back to the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Touch the gamepad. Towards the right a bit arrow will be displayed. Click that to open up the menu on the gamepad. There will be 3 big options - the top one is the one to switch between gamepad and tv.